# Difference between GAE Storage pricing and Google Cloud Storage pricing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

What's the difference between:

Google AppEngine Storage pricing https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing
$0.18 per GB per month

with

Google Cloud Storage pricing https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing $0.026    per GB per month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datastore is designed for fast access to massive amounts of any data, which can be indexed. It is basically a non-relational database.

Cloud Storage is designed for efficient storage of files.